# Create a concrete implementation and then register it

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Fist of all , I use the simpleInjector.

```
private static readonly Container Container = new Container();
```

I have

```
public interface ILine
{
    Guid LineId { get; set; }

    void Run();
}
```

And

```
public class CallFlowApplication : ICallFlowApplication
{
    private ILine _lineApi;
    public CallFlowApplication(ILine line)
    {
        _lineApi = line;
    }

    public void HandleCall()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now also:

```
static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        VoiceElementsCallFlowService.Container = Container;
        Container.Register<ICallFlowService, VoiceElementsCallFlowService>();

        Container.Register<ICallFlowApplication, CallFlowApplication>();

        // TODO: Register your application here
        Container.Register<IApplicationFactory>(() => new ApplicationFactory
                {
                    { 1, () => Container.GetInstance<CallFlowApplication>() }
                }, Lifestyle.Singleton);
    }
```

When I play the application, I got the error at the code `Container.Verify();`

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type ICallFlowApplication failed. The constructor of type CallFlowApplication contains the parameter with name 'line' and type ILine that is not registered. Please ensure ILine is registered, or change the constructor of CallFlowApplication.

My question is that I am not sure how to deal with `ILine` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register `ILine` with your concrete implementation you have for `ILine`, `VoiceElementsLine`:

```
Container.Register<ILine, VoiceElementsLine>();
Container.Register<ICallFlowApplication, CallFlowApplication>();
```

When the container is attempting to instantiate `CallFlowApplication`, the constructor for that takes an `ILine` but you haven't registered an `ILine` so it doesn't have anything to give it which is why it fails. You need to tell the container "hey, when something asks for an `ILine` give it a `VoiceElementsLine`."

Comment: I have a class `public class VoiceElementsLine : ILine`. Do you mean I need to place a code `ILine line = new VoiceElementsLine();
            Container.Register<ILine, line>();`?

Comment: @Love no, register it as `Container.Register<ILine, VoiceElementsLine>();`.